# How to list valid tx power for my wifi device

Tags: 16.04, wireless, power-management

I am trying to lower the tx power of my wi-fi card.

Using the following command

> iwconfig wlan0 **txpower 0**

I am also tried the following:

> iw dev wlan0 set **txpower fixed 10mBm**

But command execute without any error message. No matter what values I use the TX-Power does not change

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated  Tx-Power=19 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  *You've tagged you're using an EOL/ESM thus off-topic release of Ubuntu*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `iw` for this, you need to first bring the network down:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 down
```

Then you can set the fixed `txpower` value:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed 10mBm
```

And finally bring the network back up:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```